# Magento 2: There are no commands defined in the "cron" namespace

Tags: magento2, cron, magento-cron

Magento 2.4.3-p1

When I run `bin/magento cron:run` on the command line all is fine. No issues.

When I let it run by the system's cron it does not work and I get this in the `/var/log/magento.cron.log` all the time: `There are no commands defined in the "cron" namespace.`

This happens to the same setup on two rather different systems (local dev environment and remote production).

I have other 2.4.3-p1 shops with the same local/remote setup without any issues.

I already checked the file permissions but nothing helps. Even a radical `chmod -R 777 *` does not make a difference.

I ran out of options. What could be the issue here?

Thank you

EDIT:

This ist the log entry in debug.log and system.log:

```
[2021-11-25 16:20:02] main.ERROR: There are no commands defined in the "cron" namespace.
#0 /vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(657): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->findNamespace('cron')
#1 /vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(237): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->find('cron:run')
#2 /vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(115): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#3 /vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(149): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#4 /bin/magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. In my case I had no problems on testing or local environments, but production always fails. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2 and run `n98-magerun2.phar sys:cron:run CRON_JOB_NAME`

Answer (score 0):

In my case it's related to my cache/Redis configuration. I run multiple M2 instances on one server sharing one Redis instance for cache. There are prefixes in Redis cache keys but it looks like such approach is no go. I'll install Redis instance per each M2 vhost.